# When was Charlotte Mew's "The Trees Are Down" published?

Tags: poetry, charlotte-mew

The poem is available [at the Poetry Foundation](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/51731/the-trees-are-down). A Slideshare [presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/ShanAmbrose/the-trees-are-down) makes the unsourced claim that the trees mentioned were cut down in the "early 1920s". However, the level of grief expressed within the poem suggests that another event might have influenced the emotions expressed within the poem. I suspect (without evidence) that her sister's predeceasing her by a short period could possibly have influenced these emotions.

Despite this, no source appears to explicitly date the poem, hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It seems to have been first published posthumously in 1929.**

The book *A New Matrix for Modernism: A Study of the Lives and Poetry of Charlotte Mew and Anna Wickham* by Nelljean Rice [calls it](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JfuAAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA33&dq=charlotte+mew+the+trees+are+down&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0vMLjkNrWAhXGJJoKHYgEBuQQ6AEIOTAE#v=onepage&q=charlotte%20mew%20the%20trees%20are%20down&f=false) "one of her last poems", and she died on 24 March 1928.

The book *In Nature's Name: An Anthology of Women's Writing and Illustration, 1780-1930* edited by Barbara T. Gates [sources it](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UVTFe0Ak9_AC&pg=PA207&dq=charlotte+mew+the+trees+are+down&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0vMLjkNrWAhXGJJoKHYgEBuQQ6AEIKjAB#v=onepage&q=charlotte%20mew%20the%20trees%20are%20down&f=false) to her collection *The Rambling Sailor*, which was [first published in 1929](http://trove.nla.gov.au/work/8600192?selectedversion=NBD1304180).

So it's not clear exactly when it was *written*, but the late 1920s seems like the best guess.

Comment: This was very helpful. I'll mark it as the accepted answer tomorrow if no one else suggests anything. I'd add that a little more digging had me find [this](http://studymore.org.uk/ymew.htm#TheTreesAreDown) - this is admittedly completely unsourced and I don't have access to _The Chapbook_.

Comment: @AnagramAtaf Huh, interesting. That cites 1923 as the publication date for "The Trees are Down", but it also cites 1922 for *The Rambling Sailor* while the more reputable-looking source I found says TRS was first published in 1929.

Comment: It is possible that the National Library of Australia reference was autogenerated and referred to a specific edition, I suppose. This website is slightly less dodgy than it initially appears (it's not autogenerated based on random snippets stolen from the internet as I initially thought - the website claims that there's an academic behind it) but it could still be unreliable nevertheless.